# Capistrano pseudo-terminal (pty) not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I set up a basic config/deploy.rb file with a task:

```
task :blah do
  run ". ~/blah.sh"
end
```

And on the server, the blah.sh file just prompts for input:

```
while true; do
    read -p "Say something: " blah
done
```

Capistrano connects to my server just fine, and normal commands work as well. When I run `cap blah` it prompts me for input, but whatever I type, it's not sending back to the server. The output looks like:

```
  * 2013-02-13 19:12:36 executing `blah'
  * executing ". ~/blah.sh"
    servers: ["192.81.214.76"]
    [192.81.214.76] executing command
 ** [out :: 192.81.214.76] Say something:
```

And it doesn't respond no matter what I type.

Note I did set `default_run_options[:pty] = true`

I'm not even sure if this is a problem with my local setup or the server. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like capistrano was not built for this: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.capistrano.general/5038

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a sh script, use a rake task (that's what I did, anyway)

```
namespace :interact do
    task :say_something do
        system("read -p 'Say something: ' blah && echo $blah")
    end
end
```

then set up a capistrano task with a run command that can handle communication back and forth with the remote server

```
namespace :interact do
    task :say_something do
        run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && #{rake} interact:say_something", :pty => true do |ch, stream, data|
            if data =~ /Say something:/
                # prompt, and then send the response to the remote process
                ch.send_data(Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt("Say something (to the remote server): ") + "\n")
            else
                # use the default handler for all other text
                Capistrano::Configuration.default_io_proc.call(ch, stream, data)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks to http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.capistrano.general/5038 on which this is based